# I need to leave certain keys in the dictionary, and delete unnecessary ones

Tags: python, generator

I need to implement a generator that will return the values ​​of the keys of the dictionary array through yield. 
If one argument is passed to the generator, then output only the value of the passed key. If more than one argument, then return the dictionaries with the keys that were passed to the generator
Display output in one or two lines

What I've tried

```py
def field(items, *args):
    assert len(args) > 0
    # Необходимо реализовать генератор
    if (len(args) == 1):
        for es in items:
            if (args[0] in es and args[0] != 'None'):
                yield es[args[0]]
    else:
        for i in range(len(items)):
            en_value = []
            dict = {}
            for j in range(len(args)):
                if args[j] != None:
                    en_value.append(items[i][args[j]])
                    dict[str(args[j])] = en_value[j]
            yield dict
```

**Expected:**

```py
print(field(goods, 'title'))
```

> **output:** 'Cover', 'Sofa', 'Stellach', 'Vechalka'

```py
print(field(goods, 'title', 'price'))
```

> **output:** {'title' : 'Cover', 'price' : 2000}, {'title' : 'Sofa', 'price' : 5300}

And it works, but does not if I do:

```py
for idx in field(goods, None, 'color'):
    print(idx)
```

**Error:**

> IndexError: list index out of range.

**Question:**

Can you help me fix this beautiful?

Comment: ``dict`` is a reserved keyword

Comment: @MohammadMasoumi: no, `dict` is merely the name of a built-in type. It is not reserved, nor is it even a keyword. It's not the best idea to use it as a variable name, but it doesn't hurt either, certainly not as a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

If I got correctly what you want, your `field` function should look like this:

```
def field(items, *args):
    clargs = [x for x in args if x is not None]
    assert len(clargs) > 0
    if len(clargs) == 1:
        for es in items:
            if clargs[0] in es:
                yield es[clargs[0]]
    else:
        for es in items:
            yield {j:es[j] for j in clargs}
```

Using your `goods` list:

```
In [9]: list(field(goods, 'title'))
Out[9]: ['Cover', 'Sofa', 'Stellach', 'Vechalka']

In [10]: list(field(goods, 'title', 'price'))
Out[10]: 
[{'price': 2000, 'title': 'Cover'},
 {'price': 5300, 'title': 'Sofa'},
 {'price': 7000, 'title': 'Stellach'},
 {'price': 800, 'title': 'Vechalka'}]
```

Comment: Still not sure about your check on None... what are you trying to do in that case?

Comment: Just this:         for es in items:
            yield {j : es[j] for j in args if j != None}

Comment: So you want to remove any None value in the argument list if present?

Comment: Yes, make sense. I've edited the answer, I think is better to remove the None values before checking the lenght of the list. Seems more consistent to me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199697/discussion-between---and-valentino).